# ¿Por que IE8 no me reconoce el evento .Click de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, click, internet-explorer-8

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual necesito mandar a llamar un botón asp por medio de JavaScript después de cargar un archivo en un FileUpload, utilizo la sentencia `document.getElementById('nameButton').click();` en Chrome, Firefox me funciona correctamente pero en IE8 crashea y me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

[image: ScreenShot del Error]

y este es mi codigo :

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function precargar() {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnCargaImg.ClientID%>').click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div> <asp:Label ID="lblMsj" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label><br /><br />
              <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp" runat="server" onchange="precargar();" 
                OnPreRender="fileUp_PreRender"></asp:FileUpload><br /><br />
            <br /><br />
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCargarImg" runat="server" Text="Cargar Imagen" OnClick="btnCargarImg_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Este es el resultado en Google Chrome y Firefox...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reemplaza `click` por `onclick` y dime que pasa.

Comment: En IE8 y 9 prácticamente no hay nada de compatibilidad para javascript y css, verás que si funciona en las versiones 10 y 11. Te recomiendo buscar una solución para que te acepten desde esas versiones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder amigo ¿Tendrás alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Parece que hay un fallo tipográfico, debería ser `btnCargarImg` pero pone `btnCargaImg`. Lo cual es raro, porque entonces no te debería funcionar en ninguno de los navegadores. Deberías compartir el código HTML generado y no el código asp que lo genera para que podamos reproducir el error.

Comment: @Einer Me aparece otro error  **Excepción no controlada en línea 95, columna 13 en http://localhost:62141/Atendedor/Controles/Seguimiento.aspx

0x800a01b6 - Error en tiempo de ejecución de Microsoft JScript: El objeto no acepta esta propiedad o método

Si hay un controlador para esta excepción, el programa puede continuar de forma segura.**

Comment: Y, como comentario aparte, esto es para algo corporativo, ¿no? Porque de lo contrario, te diría que lo ignoraras: Microsoft quitó el soporte para IE8 hace ya más de 2 años, no deberías priorizar su soporte en desarrollo a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario.

Comment: @UriSánchez creo que estaba bien antes de tu edición. Sólo me llama la atención que tenga un ID diferente en el lado del servidor y del cliente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en efecto amigo, el detalle que es una función necesaria ya que este método agrega archivos adjuntos y bueno en su mayoría hay personas que solo saben usar IE y levantan reportes que no funciona la el metodo.

Comment: OK. Acabo de ver que es al adjuntar archivos... y que parece ser un comportamiento normal de IE8 para evitar problemas de seguridad. Voy a ver si encuentro documentación que lo soporte y te lo pongo en una respuesta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entonces no hay forma de como abordar este tema?

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer con ese botón? Porque parece que lo que quieres es que se envíe el formulario cuando se cambie el fichero y ese es precisamente el comportamiento que intenta evitar IE8.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no amigo, el envió del formulario es independiente, la logica es cargo el archivo en el FileUpload, ese desencadena el método  **precargar();** de JS el cual acciona el botón y este a su vez carga los archivos de manera visual para el usuario, esto permite cargar hasta 3 archivos ya si el usuario lo desea envía los tres archivos, pero en IE no carga ningún archivo por que crashea....

Comment: Adjunte la imagen de como funciona en otros navegadores y en IE no logra hacer nada.....

Comment: @UriSánchez Estoy 99% seguro de que el problema es por la política de seguridad de IE8 que comentaba antes, lo que no me termina de quedar del todo claro es lo que se supone que hace el botón que se llama desde precargar, para saber si podría haber un modo de evitar el problema. Sería mejor si pudieras crear un [mcve] (sólo con HTML, JS y CSS, sin ASP) para reproducir el problema.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Tal vez tenga que ver con color de fondo. Dejé la cita como respuesta pues no cabe como comentario.

Comment: @Rubén puede, aunque creo que tiene más que ver con [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335390/3695983). IE8 no permitiendo que se manipule nada relacionado con un input=file con JavaScript por motivos de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente esté relacionado con un bug de IE 8 que tiene que ver con el color del fondo.

Dejo la cita textual, fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Browser_compatibility

> ### Browser compatibility
>
> #### Internet Explorer
>
> Internet Explorer 8 & 9 suffer
> from a bug where elements with a computed background-color of
> transparent that are overlaid on top of other element(s) won't receive
> click events. Any click events will be fired at the underlying
> element(s) instead. See this live example for a demonstration.
>
> ### Known workarounds for this bug:
>
> For IE9 only: Set background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) Set opacity: 0 and
> an explicit background-color other than transparent
> For IE8 and IE9: Set filter: alpha(opacity=0); and an explicit background-color other
> than transparent

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos pero no pude resolver este detalle. Lo que hice fue realizar un método C# y consumirlo desde Ajax para que funcionara, de otra manera no pude replicar mi flujo.